# How to find values from one table missing in another?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I am a Junior Developer. I have been asked to create a subquery to solve this problem. If the question is not clear then please let me know so I can provide more details.

I have two tables,`Article` and `Author`. I have been tasked with doing the following:

> Select distinct Author values that don't exist in the Author table. The result should not contain any Authors that are NULL or Empty String. The purpose is to find any Author names that ARE in the Article table but NOT in the Author table.

I have Author column in both Tables. Can this problem be solved by joining these two tables?

I have tried

```
select distinct name 
from author 
where name NOT IN ( select author 
                    from article 
                    where author IS NOT NULL)
```

It doesn't give me the result that I want :(

Comment: If you want in Article and not in Auther then that query is backwards

Comment: I suspect that this question can be confusing for beginners. You are using the name "Author" for both a table name and a field, right? And that is probably why I am confused by "_select distinct Author values that don't exist in the Author table_". I think "_find any Author names that ARE in the Article table but NOT in the Auther table_" explains it.

Comment: Also you say _Author column in both Tables_ but the name is _name_ in the author table, correct?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I assume that you have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Author(AutorID INT, Name VARCHAR(50));  
CREATE TABLE Article(ArticleID INT, Article VARCHAR(MAX),Author VARCHAR(50));
```

Now to achieve your result just run the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Article.Author WHERE Article.Author NOT IN 
(SELECT Author.Name FROM Author) AND Article.Author IS NOT NULL
AND Article.Author != '';
```

Answer (score 5):

```
select author from article where author IS NOT NULL and author <> ''
except 
select name   from author
```

since any comparison the null is false I think below works

```
select author from article where author <> ''
except 
select name   from author
```

Comment: This is the most elegant reply - +1. If there are article.authors which are blank strings in article.author - you need to add `AND author != ''`.

Comment: This might be confusing for beginners. In _select author_, author is a field, right? In _from author_, author is a table, correct? Well at least this comment might help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You need only one column in the final output from Article table. So need to join Article and Author table. This can be done using subquery. 
Please Try this:

```
select distinct name 
from article 
where name not in (select name from Author) 
and name is not null 
and name != ''
```